# ADF - How to copy data from an excel sheet referring to the part of the file name

Tags: azure-data-factory

What I'm trying to do is copy data from an excel doc in a blob to a db. I want to access the file using 'CodeMapping' only since it's original name is like this 'CodeMapping-acbcb08e-gca6-457a-8g07-273941021w5z'
How should I do it? Can someone help me?

Copy activity - This is what I tried. But this is wrong
[image]

Dataset

[image]

Comment: Hi sav, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleas use:

```
CodeMapping*.xlsx
```

[image]

This expression mean access the .xlsx file which filename start with "CodeMapping".

Ref:

1. [Blob storage as a source type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#blob-storage-as-a-source-type)
2. [Source transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#source-transformation)